# git pull: keeps telling me to stash local changes before pulling

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

When I am trying to pull my git repository with "git pull", it keeps telling me that I have local changes although I have not touched any of the mentioned files. Can someone explain this behavior and knows a solution?

git status:

```
    # On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   src/component/Provider.java
#   modified:   src/data/Cascading.java
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

**Solved the problem.** It was actually my fault not noticing that the remote repository has been reset to a previous version. Nevertheless if you experience this, the solution explained by Max Woolf will work!

Comment: what if you make a `git diff` or just do a `git commit . -m "."`??

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: The correct mindset in these situations is that Git is right and you are wrong.
You might have done something that Git considers a change; please post the output of "git status" for review.

Comment: So what changes does Git think you've made to the files (`git diff`)?

Comment: It's even telling you which files are modified, Provider.java and Cascading.java.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It sounds like your local branch does not have all of the changes on `origin`.

Firstly, stash your changes

```
git stash
```

Then, pull in the changes from `origin`.

```
git fetch origin && git rebase origin/(branch name)
```

Next, add the stash back in to your working directory:

```
git stash pop
```

Comment: It looks like you could also achieve the same by calling `git fetch origin --autostash` which stashes and pops for you. Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/2.17.0#Documentation/git-pull.txt---autostash

Answer (score 5):

add all the files (adds all the files you changed)

```
git add .
```

then stash your changes

```
git stash
```

then you should be able to

```
git checkout branch && git pull
```

you have probably touched those files and you can go to the files and check with lines that have been touched. I usually use vscode for this. You can also just restore those files by git restore.

Answer (score 2):

Git simply can't pull the changes if the files you have edited locally were changed on the remote. Basically, you have two choices:

- stage and commit your changes, then Git will try to merge it during the pull (or ask for your help);
- stash the changes, which puts them aside so you could pull the remote code and then re-apply your modifications.